# How to get the video from my inbuilt cam(inside)? (Mulit-cam in my Surface Book 2)

Tags: video, camera, processing

I want the Video of my Cam into Processing Sketch.

I have an Surface Book 2 with 2 Cams one at the front(Display) and another one at the back.

I tried to use the guide from the website with the code:

```
import processing.video.*;
Capture cam;
void setup() {
  size(640, 480);
  String[] cameras = Capture.list();
  if (cameras.length == 0) {
    println("There are no cameras available for capture.");
    exit();
  } else {
    println("Available cameras:");
    for (int i = 0; i < cameras.length; i++) {
      println(cameras[i]);
    }
    // The camera can be initialized directly using an 
    // element from the array returned by list():
    cam = new Capture(this, cameras[0]);
    cam.start();     
  }      
}

void draw() {
  if (cam.available() == true) {
    cam.read();
  }
  image(cam, 0, 0);
  // The following does the same, and is faster when just drawing the image
  // without any additional resizing, transformations, or tint.
  //set(0, 0, cam);
}
```

But then I only get some weird frames with a green tint on it. And when I connect another Cam via USB its working just fine, after I looked into Capture.list() and edited the Number to the according Source (USB Camera).

If I do the same with the other listings, I'm getting always the same Problem. 
What I found out was that on the backside cam the Light goes on.

Maybe someone knows how to solve my Problem with those 2 Cams and then using only the front one.

Thanks for helping me out :D

Edit: Another thing is, if I look after cam.available(), its nearly always false. 
Then for only one loop in draw its true and then there are a few seconds only with false again. I dont understand why my Cam is not available with the USB Camera this Problem isnt there at all.

Comment: I don't use Processing, but it sounds like camera is outputting YUV but Processing is expecting RGB.

Comment: Okay thanks, do you know a way to change the output to rgb inside Windows or Processing?

Comment: @Maxi I'd start by looking in your camera settings or in the library documentation.

Comment: This is hackish but you can install VLC, it can read from your webcam. Its command line transcoding options are a bit complicated but once you figure out something usable you can send the output to a named pipe. In your application just read from the pipe.